# Data not loading in datatable after echoing json data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixPCN.jpg)I have a json data which i want to display in the datatables using ajax. The screen only shows the loading data but in actual it doesn't load the data. Here is my datatables code.`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').DataTable( {
      "bProcessing": true,
     // "bServerSide": true,
     "sAjaxSource": "all_data.php",
   //  "sAjaxDataProp": "data"
   "aoColumns": [
   { "mDataProp": "id" },
   { "mDataProp": "Vendor Code" },
   { "mDataProp": "Vendor Name" },
   { "mDataProp": "Category/Season" },
   { "mDataProp": "Product" },
   { "mDataProp": "Price" },
   { "mDataProp": "BLP" } ,
   { "mDataProp": "Quote Sent By" },
   { "mDataProp": "Sent On" },

   { "mDataProp": "Sent To" },

   { "mDataProp": "Link" }

   ]

 } );

 });
```

Here is my json file

```
[{"id":"1","vendor_code":"PBH053","vendor_name":"Specialty Polyfilms","category":"Food Wrap","product":"briefs","price":"0","blp":"GBP 0.290","quote_sent_by":"Martie Sir","quote_sent_on":"2023-09-16","sent_to_buyer":"Sarah spencer","Link":"link"},{"id":"2","vendor_code":"PBH055","vendor_name":"Specialty Polyfilms","category":"Food Wrap","product":"briefs","price":"0","blp":"GBP 0.290","quote_sent_by":"Martie Sir","quote_sent_on":"2023-09-16","sent_to_buyer":"Sarah spencer","Link":"link"}]
```

Here is my HTML

```
<table  width="100%" id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0">

     <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Vendor Code</th>
              <th>Vendor Name</th>
              <th>Category/Season</th>
              <th>Product</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>BLP</th>
              <th>Quote Sent By</th>
              <th>Sent On</th>
              <th>Sent To</th>            
              <th>Link</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
             <th>#</th>
             <th>Vendor Code</th>
             <th>Vendor Name</th>
             <th>Category/Season</th>
             <th>Product</th>
             <th>Price</th>
             <th>BLP</th>
             <th>Quote Sent By</th>
             <th>Sent On</th>
             <th>Sent To</th>
             <th>Link</th>

           </tr>
         </tfoot>
       </table>
```

php code

```
<?php
require("connection.php");
$data=array();


$query="SELECT * FROM quote_system";
$result=mysqli_query($dbCon,$query)or die(mysqli_error($dbCon));
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{

    $row['id'];
    $row['vendor_code'];
    $row['vendor_name']; 
    $row['category'];
    $row['product']; 
    $row['price']; 
    $row['blp']; 
    $row['quote_sent_by']; 
    $row['quote_sent_on']; 
    $row['sent_to_buyer']; 
    $row['Link'];


    $data[]=$row;
}

//print_r($data);
//$data= $data.map(JSON.parse);
echo json_encode($data);



?>
```

Comment: can you show us your php code ?

Comment: Included the code

Comment: did you include everything properly ?

Comment: yes i did this is the error

Comment: datatables.min.js:74 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)

Comment: may you share your sql code please

Comment: ill correct it for you

Comment: I have included the php as well as sql code

Comment: where is the sql code ?

Comment: I have include an image at the beginning of the question

Comment: please post sql code here

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM quote_system"; 
$result=mysqli_query($dbCon,$query)or die(mysqli_error($dbCon));
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{

 $row['id'];
 $row['vendor_code'];
 $row['vendor_name']; 
 $row['category'];
 $row['product']; 
 $row['price']; 
 $row['blp']; 
 $row['quote_sent_by']; 
 $row['quote_sent_on']; 
 $row['sent_to_buyer']; 
 $row['Link'];
 
 
 $data[]=$row;
}

//print_r($data);
//$data= $data.map(JSON.parse);
echo json_encode($data);

Comment: the code of your sql table

Comment: you have to export it

Comment: its too long will not fit in comment section

Comment: then post it in your answer